# Is there a better way to see if a file is being written to?

Tags: php

We have a FreeBSD server with samba that employees copy image files on to, which then get uploaded to our web servers (this way they don't have to mess with ftp). Sometimes, if the upload script is running at the same time as files are being copied, it can upload an incomplete file.

We fixed this by getting the list of files along with the file sizes, then waiting 5 seconds and rechecking the file sizes. If the sizes match then its save to upload, if they don't match it checks again in another 5 seconds.

This seems like an odd way to check if the files are being written to. is there a better, more simple way of doing this?

Comment: `if (!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) { // file is locked for writing` ?

Comment: not sure if `flock()` and samab's locks will see each other reliably - had some problems there years ago

Comment: @EugenRieck Just been playing with it on a Fedora box and it seems to work, but I guess YMMV...

Comment: @DaveRandom As I said, this was years ago ... PHP4 and Samba 2 (on Linux 2.4) IIRC, might as well work perfectly now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `flock` function http://php.net/flock - when writing a file obtain an exclusive lock `flock($handle, LOCK_EX)`, after it is written release the lock `flock($handle, LOCK_UN)`.

The upload script could try to obtain the exclusive writing lock too, if it succeeds it is Okay to move the file, otherwise no.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I forgot about the users copying the files to the server through samba... So there is no space to use `flock` while copying... But the upload script could still use `flock($handle, LOCK_EX)` to see, if it is successful or not.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to `shell_exec()` smbstatus(1), e.g. `smbstatus -LB` to check for locked files

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to copy the files to a temp folder on the Samba server and then, when fully copied and flushed, move, (ie, unlink/link, not copy again), them to the upload folder.